# Can't work while changing old mysql to pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have changed old MYSQL code to PDO code, but pdo code doesn't work properly. Old mysql code works perfectly. PDO doesn't display result. I can't find where is code error in PDO. Actually it is api for APK

**Old MYSQL**

```
<?php
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
        if(isset($_GET['cat_id'])){
            $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c,tbl_news n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id and c.cid='".$_GET['cat_id']."' ORDER BY n.id DESC";          
            $result = mysql_query($query);  
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['latest_news'])){
                $limit=$_GET['latest_news'];        
                $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c,tbl_news n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT $limit";         
                $result = mysql_query($query);
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['apps_details'])){ 
                $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_settings WHERE id='1'";       
                $result = mysql_query($query);
        }
        else{   
                $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category ORDER BY cid DESC";         
                $result = mysql_query($query);
        }
        $set = array();

        $total_records = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($total_records >= 1){

          while ($link = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

            $set['NewsApp'][] = $link;
          }
        }
         echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set));  
    ?>
```

PDO

```
if(isset($_GET['cat_id'])){
        $result=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c,tbl_news n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id and c.cid='".$_GET['cat_id']."' ORDER BY n.id DESC");          
}
else if(isset($_GET['latest_news'])){
        $limit=$_GET['latest_news'];
        $result=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c,tbl_news n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT $limit");         
}
else if(isset($_GET['apps_details'])){ 
        $result=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_settings WHERE id='1'");       
}
else{   
$result=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category ORDER BY cid DESC");         
}
$set = array();
$result->execute();
$total_records = $result->fetchColumn();
if($total_records >= 1){
    while($link=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $set['NewsApp'][] = $link;
  }
}
 echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set));
```

Comment: Side note, the whole point of preparing is so you don't do this `...c.cid='".$_GET['cat_id']."'...`. That should be a parameter using `?` or `:cat_id` then using `$_GET` into the `->execute()` (or other bind method).

Comment: I don't think you want to use `PDOStatement#fetchColumn()`. Try reading the documentation for the methods you're using ~ http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Comment: Can you tell us which query, are you trying to make work? Without the passed _GET parameters, I don't think it is possible for us to know which one you are trying to make work.  In any case do more search before posting here as your question already has an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881472/use-fetch-column-and-fetchpdofetch-assoc-together

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use fetch\_column and fetch(PDO::FETCH\_ASSOC) together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881472/use-fetch-column-and-fetchpdofetch-assoc-together)

Comment: What's the point of using PDO and prepare if your just gonna concatenate user data in the SQL?  `c.cid='".$_GET['cat_id']."'`  PDO is not some "Magic Bullet" against SQLInjection, you have to use it properly for it to work.

Comment: @Cemal not a duplicate. OP wanted to use `rowCount()`, not `fetchColumn()`. Could be closed as a typo though

Comment: Please make sure you are sanitizing your input.  This is a pretty good read: http://www.phptherightway.com/#pdo_extension

Comment: @Phil the OP in other question did the same mistake and wanted to achieve the same result with slighlty different code, and it already has an accepted answer there, which is practically same as the accepted one in here.

Comment: @Cemal I suppose I should have read beyond the title ;)

Comment: you should have moved from old `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` methods if you wanted to move to PDO you should have read some tutorials on how to use PDO_mysql check this out it might help you understand and read it all don't just scan for code and try to follow it explains a lot in the text https://www.sitepoint.com/migrate-from-the-mysql-extension-to-pdo/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I felt inclined to add this (this is not an answer)

In your "PDO" code I see 2 places where it's vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.  Now you may be upgrading so it will work with PHP 7 but to ignore this is, tragic.

Specifically

```
if(isset($_GET['cat_id'])){
    $result=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c,tbl_news n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id and c.cid='".$_GET['cat_id']."' ORDER BY n.id DESC");          

}else if(isset($_GET['latest_news'])){
    $limit=$_GET['latest_news'];
    $result=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c,tbl_news n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT $limit");         

}
```

Both `$_GET` and by extension `$limit` are user input you directly concatenate into the SQL.  Anytime you concatenate anything into a SQL command it needs to be bound or thoroughly sanitized (such as checked against a white list, for example in the case of variable column names such as when picking sorting).   This needs to be done "In clear view of the query"  In other words if you cant see in the same place how the input is cleaned it needs to be bound.  This is what I call Point of failure.

To fix them do it this way.

```
$params = [];
if(isset($_GET['cat_id'])){
    $result=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c,tbl_news n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id and c.cid=:cat_id' ORDER BY n.id DESC");          
    $params = [':cat_id' => $_GET['cat_id']];
}else if(isset($_GET['latest_news'])){
    $result=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c,tbl_news n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT :limit"); 
    // to bind to limit clause you have to use BindValue
    $result->bindValue(':limit', (int)$_GET['latest_news'], PDO::PARAM_INT);        
}

 ... other code ...

$result->execute($params);
```

You could use `$result->bindValue(':cat_id', $_GET['cat_id'])`  in the first case, but I wanted to show the array method of binding as well as the `bind` call method.   If you did that you could skip the `$param` all together.  But the array method is useful if you have a lot of variables to bind, so I thought I would show that as well.

Not everything can be bound, such as column names.  An example of this would be allowing a user to pick what column to sort on.  This seams like a small thing but even there you cannot just concatenate user input in your Query.  In this case as I said before I would check it against a list of column names they are allowed to sort on and in clear view of the query so there is no way to bypass the check.

For these cases you can do something like this (say $_GET['orderby'] = 'first'):

```
  $whitelist = ['first','last','age'];

  $orderby = false;
  if(!empty($_GET['orderby']) && false !== ( $index = array_search($_GET['orderby'], $whitelist))){
       $orderby = $whitelist[$index]; 
  }

  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1';
  if($orderby) $sql =. ' ORDER BY '.$orderby;
```

In this way we can check the user input and not actually use it, the value of `$orderby` is the value of `$whitelist[$index]` and so even here no user input is added to the query.  This is done if there is some code error then we wont ever have to worry about something sneaking in.

Even if you think it's canned data it needs to be cleaned or bound.  Code can change and it take much less effort to do this on the front end then to deal with the consequences if your site suffers a major hack.  An example of what you think of canned data could be something stored in `$_SESSION` but because it's stored in a global place, some code update could change where that value comes from and it's not clear where that change is made that it makes a query buried somewhere  in the code venerable.  This is why even caned data needs to be cleaned right at the query.

It can be a bit confusing at first, but it really is quite simple and easy to do.  Hope that helps.

Now Fix It!

Comment: `s/:skip/:limit`

Comment: Thanks Phil.  I copied the Limit bind as those can bit a bit trickier then just a string bind.  Fixed!

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is you're using fetchColumn() to get the number of total records, when you probably want rowCount():

```
$total_records = $result->rowCount();
```

The fetchColumn() call simply grabs the next column from the next record in the result set. So if your query returns 2 rows like this:

```
fruit  | color
--------------
apple  | red
grapes | green
```

...then calling fetchColumn() on the result after executing it would give you "apple". Meanwhile, rowCount() would give you the number 2 (two rows).

EDIT: Also pay attention to Rasclatt's advice in the first comment regarding setting up your queries to use parameters. It's very good advice.

Comment: Or just skip the column count and iterate the result-set anyway. There's little difference and not all DB engines provide a row count for `SELECT` queries

Comment: From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.rowcount.php) ~ _"If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. **However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.**"_

Comment: Not all engines do, but the asker appears to have been converting from the old mysql extension, and MySQL does support it. -shrug-

Comment: Yep, I know. They include that because of the variety of database engines supported by PDO. But if you know what your database is going to be, and it supports it...

Comment: Still totally redundant to use it as a gateway to iterating the results. Iterating an empty collection results in the same logic

Comment: Yup, I agree. :)

Comment: `$total_records = $result->fetchColumn();` should be removed or it will advance the cursor and mess up the `while` fetch part.